# Problema com '.data()' e seu valor dentro de um if

Tags: jquery, atributos

Estou criando uns `If`'s para não perder o costume de usá-los, porém ao tentar algo um pouco diferente do que costumo fazer, ocorre um erro, o `if` não funciona. Como posso corrigir ? Tentei nos seguintes modos:

```
if($('.carousel-indicators li.active').data('slide-to').val() = 0){
    console.log('Teste');
};
ERRO : Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

e

```
if($('.carousel-indicators li.active').data('slide-to') = 0){
    console.log('Teste');
};
ERRO : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).val is not a function
```

Comment: Faltou um sinal de igual `.val() == 0` e por que está usando `.data().val()`??

Comment: Porque simplesmente o .data() não havia funcionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dois problemas:

- o `.data()` já te dá uma *String*, não precisas (nem deves) usar o `.val()`
- comparação deve ser feita com `==` ou `===`, usar só `=` é uma atribuição.

Solução:

```
if($('.carousel-indicators li.active').data('slide-to') == 0){
    console.log('Teste');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Quando você compara alguma coisa precisa usar `==` ou `===` (comparação strict).
O `=` é para atribuir valor à alguma variável.

Comment: Porquê o `-1`?  A resposta está certa e explica o problema do AP...

Comment: Eu também acho que o problema provèm daí, não percebi o menos `-1`, a nao ser que me tenha escapado alguma coisa @Sergio

Comment: @Miguel alguem deu -1 e outra pessoa +1 pra compensar, provavelmente o Sergio

Comment: @Miguel eu tb não, por isso (e porque a resposta está certa) dei `+1`

Comment: Yap também acho